# SSH'ing to my machine attaches an existing screen session and detaching it ends my SSH session

Tags: ssh, screen, remote-desktop

ssh'ing to my Ubuntu machine automatically attaches an existing screen session and detaching ends my ssh session

---

What I want is to be able to ssh to my Ubuntu machine without automatically attaching to the screen session on that machine.  Or at least, I should be able to to detach from that screen session w/o ending my ssh session .. right?  Doesn't seem to work.

This so that I can attempt to run `firefox --display <whichever one is being forwarded to my ssh session>`, so that I can debug a website that the remote Ubuntu machine is running (via localhost).

Best case scenario is that I could just remote-desktop to my Ubuntu machine.  But it's not set up to allow remote-desktop, and I see no way to set it up remotely via shell/ssh.  Also, it sounds like you need a static IP in order to remote desktop to an Ubuntu machine (so I keep reading).

Comment: What ssh command are you connecting with? A default ssh into a machine shouldn't connect to a running screen session unless you specify it as the command parameter to ssh or have it in the login script...

Comment: via a vpn connection:ssh -X <hostname>

Comment: So how do you automatically connect to a running screen session - is there a login script?

Comment: I don't see the word "screen" in /etc/login.defs anywhere and


I should mention that byobu (a nice screen wrapper utility) is running on the remote machine.  It must be doing something... Also note that it's a fairly recent install of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Original Answer

It seems that your `byobu` installation has probably edited one of your login script files. You should search these, namely

- `~/.bashrc`
- `~/.profile`
- Possibly the system-wide files too

for `byobu` or `screen` - you can use grep or just open up the file.

E.g. Open `~/.bashrc` and search for `byobu`, namely something like

```
if [ $SSH_TTY ] && [ ! $WINDOW ]; then
    SCREENLIST=`screen -ls | grep 'Attached'`
    if [ $? -eq "0" ]; then
        echo -e "Screen is already running and attached:\n ${SCREENLIST}"
    else
        type -P byobu &>/dev/null && byobu -U -R || screen -U -R
    fi
fi
```

Comment out this section to restore normal `ssh` behaviour.

See [here for more information](http://fransdejonge.com/2011/06/more-fun-with-screen-and-ssh-with-byobu-automatic-reattaching/) about this automatic reattaching behaviour.

### This Is What Worked (see comments below)

In `~/.profile`, comment out  `_byobu_sourced=1 . /usr/bin/byobu-launch`

And if you're trying to launch an X11 Firefox session, just `ssh -X <hostname> firefox` (you may need to add the `-no-remote` flag).

Comment: Hm .. not only is nothing like that in my .bashrc but the word screen appears nowhere on any file in my home directory.

`jsplaine@xxx:~$ grep -i screen ~/*`
`jsplaine@xxx:~$`

Comment: re-ran a search with `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f|xargs grep -i screen` -- found stuff in bash_history, ./.viminfo, and ./.xsession-errors.old only

Comment: checked /usr/share/base-files/dot.bashrc, /etc/bash.bashrc, /home/jsplaine/.bashrc, and /usr/share/base-files/dot.bashrc.  No mention of screen or byobu.. : /

Comment: Even killing the screen session kicks me out of ssh, and ssh again begins a new screen session it seems.  Meh whatever -- all I need to do is run an X11 browser OR remote-desktop.

Comment: I was afraid of that - there are other places that also hold login commands, such as /etc/profile, ~/.profile, and check what scripts are in /etc/profile.d/ ... not sure which other places you could check

Comment: Sweeeet ... ~/.profile has this line in it: `_byobu_sourced=1 . /usr/bin/byobu-launch` -- Ding!  Thanks : D

Comment: Phew! - Cool, glad you found it, was running out of ideas! Edited my answer to include other files to search for anyone else with this problem!

Comment: However .. this isn't working : (  
   jsplaine@SOFTWARE1:~$ echo $DISPLAY
   localhost:10.0
   jsplaine@SOFTWARE1:~$ firefox -no-remote --display=10:0
   xcb_connection_has_error() returned true

Comment: hah and neither is adding newlines to my posts.  NONE of this stuff works http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#comment-formatting ... not my day perhaps ; p

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the display parameter when calling firefox if you used the `-X` flag to `ssh`... but if you do it should probably be `localhost:10.0`, not  `10:0`

Comment: You son of a ... !  Awesome!  What can I do to give you an upvote/street-cred/dap/karma? (seeing how the first answer wasn't quite the right one?)

Comment: @jsplaine: Well I edited the answer to include searching for the other files i.e. `.profile`) too - do you think that covers the process?

Comment: @jsplaine: Alternatively feel free to edit my answer such as to make it better match what you felt the solution was

Comment: done -- I'd vote up if I had the rep.  Thank you very much.  And if you're super bored, there's always this [Setting up remote desktop via ssh?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/172081/setting-up-remote-desktop-via-ssh-not-actually-at-the-machine-but-can-ssh) :D

Comment: Hey guys, can you clean up the answer to be what is correct? The comments are no better than an internet forum, just make the answer be what is correct!